# C returns invalid address in loop

Tags: c, pointers

I am looping through my file structure with a C program. It I hit a new folder, i appending it's path to a linked list so I can look through all subdirectories iteratively.

The program consists of:

main function, calling the iterative function (which loops through the files)

When i loop through all the files once everything works fine. However when i have a while loop in my main function to call the iterative function more often, it always fails on the second time due to segmenatation error.

So i was investigating a bit and it seems that one element of the linked list is having an invalid address.

All addresses of my elements have this format and length:  0x2398ff0 or 0x2398ee0

However the illegal pointer has an address from 0x7f3770304c58

Does anyone have any thoughts why this address is so long?

I have checked throught printf("%p", element) every new address that gets added to the linked list, and this address never appear anywhere before in the code. It like magically appears.

I was thinking about a wild pointer maybe, but after i free any pointer i set it to NULL to, which should prevent this right?

Thanks for any tip. I haven't posted the code right now cause it is very long and thought maybe there are obvious things i just dont see.

EDIT: the entire code, including main function

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void iterativefile(FILE *f, char** field, int looper){

    DIR *d;
    struct dirent *dir;

    typedef struct nextpath { // Define element type of linked list
        char *thispath;
        struct nextpath *next;
    }nextpath;

    nextpath *startpath = malloc(sizeof(nextpath));
    char * beginning = (char *) malloc(2); //create first element in linked list, starting on root node "."
    strcpy(beginning, ".");
    startpath->thispath = beginning;

    int found = 0;

    nextpath *currentzeiger = startpath;
    nextpath *firstelement = startpath;
    char *newdir, *currentfile, *currentpath;

    do {
        currentpath = currentzeiger->thispath;
        d = opendir(currentpath);
        if (!d){ //IF the path is invalid or cannot be opened

            firstelement = currentzeiger->next;
            free(currentzeiger);
            currentzeiger = firstelement;
            continue;
        }
        while((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL){
            if (dir->d_type != DT_REG){ // current element is a directory -> add it to linked list
                if (strcmp(dir->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(dir->d_name, "..") != 0){
                    newdir = (char *) malloc(2+strlen(currentpath) + strlen(dir->d_name));      
                    strcpy(newdir, currentpath);
                    strcat(newdir, "/");
                    strcat(newdir, dir->d_name);
                    nextpath *new = malloc(sizeof(nextpath)); // add new folder to linked list
                    new->thispath = NULL;
                    new->thispath = strdup(newdir);
                    new->next = currentzeiger->next;
                    currentzeiger->next = new;
                    free(newdir);
                    newdir = NULL;              
                }
            }
            else { // current element is a file -> check if already included in list, if not, add it
                currentfile = (char *) malloc(2+strlen(currentpath)+strlen(dir->d_name));
                strcpy(currentfile, currentpath);
                strcat(currentfile, "/");
                strcat(currentfile, dir->d_name);
                found = 0;
                if (field != NULL) {
                    for (int z = 0; z < looper; z++){
                        if (field[z] != NULL){
                            if(strcmp(currentfile,field[z]) == 0){
                                found = 1;
                                free(field[z]);
                                field[z] = NULL;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (found == 0){
                    char *renamefile = (char *) malloc(strlen(currentpath) + 6);
                    strcpy(renamefile, currentpath);
                    strcat(renamefile, ".cbsm");
                    free(renamefile);
                    renamefile = NULL;

                }
                free(currentfile);
                currentfile = NULL;
            }
        }

        firstelement = currentzeiger->next;
        free(currentzeiger->thispath);
        currentzeiger->thispath = NULL;
        free(currentzeiger);

        currentzeiger = firstelement;
        closedir(d);

    }while(currentzeiger != NULL);
}



int main()
{
    int counterofwhile = 1;
    while(1){
    printf("Loop number: %d\n", counterofwhile);
    counterofwhile++;
    FILE *fp = fopen("datasyn.txt", "rw+");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("FILE ERROR");
        FILE *fp = fopen("datasyn.txt", "ab+");
        iterativefile(fp, NULL, 0);
    }
    else {
        int lines = 0;
        int ch = 0;
        int len = 0;
        int max_len = 0;
        while((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
            ++len;
            if (ch == '\n'){
                if(max_len < len)
                    max_len = len;
                ++lines;
                len = 0;
            }
        }

        if (len)
            ++lines;
        fprintf(stderr, "%d lines\n", lines);
        if (lines > 0){
            int numProgs = 0;
            char *programs[lines];
            char line[max_len + 1];
            rewind(fp);
            while(fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp)){
                int new_line = strlen(line) - 1;
                if (line[new_line] == '\n')
                    line[new_line] = '\0';
                programs[numProgs++] = strdup(line);
            }

            iterativefile(fp, programs, numProgs);
            for (int j = 0; j < numProgs; j++){
            free(programs[j]);
            }
        }
        else {
            iterativefile(fp, NULL, 0);
        }
    sleep(1);


    printf("Done\n");
    fclose(fp);
    }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: try showing actual code

Comment: " thought maybe there are obvious things i just dont see."  We don't see them either.   http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .  You are probably clobbering the stack, or have some other type of buffer overflow.

Comment: You're probably calling a library function that takes a `char **` and expects a `NULL` sentinel as the last element of the array. You're probably not providing this `NULL` sentinel.

Comment: Addresses that start with 0x7F..... tend to be found on the stack on my machine (Linux).  Either you are pushing local variables into the linked list instead of using malloc to create new nodes, or you are overwriting memory with something else that just happens to contain pointers that point to memory on the stack.

Comment: the code has been uploaded :)

Comment: If `found` is `1` the `if(found==0) {...}` will not get executed but you still attempt to `free(currentfile);`.

Comment: You don't "free a pointer" (and this is hardly what you actually want). You "free the object a pointer **points to**". And do yourself a favour and use a consistent and common indentation/formatting style. Your code is pretty hard to read and it is not easily to check if nesting is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the function `iterativefile()`, you don't use `calloc()` to allocate `startpath` and you don't set `startpath->next` to null.  The memory returned by `malloc()` is not necessarily zeroed.  When you subsequently use `startpath->next`, all hell breaks loose.

You also don't use the file pointer passed into `iterativefile()`.  When you remove the parameter from the definition, you change the calls, and you've got a shadowed `fp` in `main()` (in the `if (fp == NULL)` block, you create a new `FILE *fp` which is really not needed).  It really isn't clear what else is meant to happen; you've not given clear instructions on what the program is meant to be doing.  I don't have the `datasyn.txt` file, but it shouldn't matter since the file stream is not used.  I got lots of lines like `FILE ERRORLoop number: 280` from the code, but no crash where previously I was getting a crash.

Compile with more warning options.  I called the file `fp17.c` and compiled my hacked version using:

```
gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition fp17.c -o fp17
```

With a few other simple changes (`static` before the function; `int main(void)`), the code compiled cleanly (and would have needed `-Wshadow` to spot the shadowing if it hadn't been for an 'unused variable' warning that pointed me to it).

Comment: hey jonathan! thanks a lot for your answer. using calloc instead of malloc really did the trick! thanks!